# DataGridPro table slots

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have a `<dataGridPro>` table:

[image: original table]

and now I need to make drawer in this table:

[image: drawer work]

I tried to use dataGrid slots, like toolbar on screenshot,  but I never found the slot I needed? (drawer should not overlap the content of the table, it should shift it.)

I looked in documentation DataGrid
all the slots are not work

Comment: Is that not the [`FilterPanel` slot](https://v4.mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro/#slots)?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl,  I tried it, but it didn't work out. But it doesn't seem to work the way I need it, I was told that the main content of the table has its own slot, which I can make custom and put the drawer component in it. but I never found this component